# Replacing foreach with LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following code in one of my methods:

```
foreach (var s in vars)
{
    foreach (var type in statusList)
    {
        if (type.Id == s)
        {
            Add(new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems sort of ineffective to me, and I was wondering if there was a way to substitute at least one of the foreaches wih a LINQ query. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** vars is an array of strings and the Add method adds an item to a CSLA NameValueList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: **I hadn't noticed the `break;` before**

If there could be more than one type with the relevant ID, then you need to use `FirstOrDefault` as per [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589737/replacing-foreach-with-linq-query/589770#589770) or my second code sample below.

EDIT: Removing "multi-from" version as it's unnecessarily inefficient assuming equality/hashcode works for whatever the type of `type.Id` is.

A join is probably more appropriate though:

```
var query = from s in vars
            join type in statusList on s equals type.Id
            select new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text);

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    Add(pair);
}
```

You might want to make an `AddRange` method which takes an `IEnumerable<NameValuePair>` at which point you could just call `AddRange(query)`.

Alternatively, you can use a LookUp. This version makes sure it only adds one type per "s".

```
var lookup = types.ToLookup(type => type.Id);
foreach (var s in vars)
{
    var types = lookup[s];
    if (types != null)
    {
        var type = types.First(); // Guaranteed to be at least one entry
        Add(new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text));
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is that it only goes through the list of types once to build up a dictionary, basically.

Comment: The break implies only the first match where 'type.Id = s', your solution matches all cases in the inner enumerable.

Comment: Hence the sentence starting with "if there could be..." :)

Comment: Yeah, I shoulda scrolled down too before posting the same answer  :)  Lesson for today: read more carefully.

Answer (score 12):

Basically:

```
var types =
    from s in vars
    let type = (
        from tp in statusList
        where tp.Id == s ).FirstOrDefault()
    where type != null
    select new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
foreach(var s in vars) {
    var type = statusList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == s);
    if (type != null)
        Add(new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text));
}
```

Or if vars supports `ForEach` method, this would work too (however I recommend against overLINQifying):

```
vars.ForEach(s => {
    var type = statusList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == s);
    if (type != null)
       Add(new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text));
});
```

I assumed `type` is an instance of a reference type.

Comment: I can't see how that would compile - your use of "type" on the third line won't work, because the variable isn't declared anywhere. The lambda expression in the "Any" call doesn't persist.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for noticing! I'm still wondering how I made that idiotic mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If your Add method is constructing a list, you might also try:

```
IEnumarable<NamedValuePair> result = statusList.Where(type => type.Id == s).Select(new NameValuePair(type => type.Id, type.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bart de Smet](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/26/the-missing-operator-foreach.aspx) has an implementation of an extension ForEach for IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an answer with a group join, so here's one:

```
var result = vars
  .GroupJoin
  (
    statusList,
    s => s,
    type => type.Id,
    (s, g) => g.Any() ? g.First() : null
  )
  .Where(type => type != null)
  .Select(type => new NameValuePair(type.Id, type.Text));
```